# Wordpress backoffice doesn't import Carbon fields javascript packages with Bedrock roots stack mu-plugins

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, carbon-fields

I’m setting up a new WordPress project with Trellis roots stack. I tried an installation with carbon fields as must used plugin. But I can't make it worked. The containers shows up but impossible to have some fields displayed.

I have tried many possibilities from many versions from the carbon fields documentation. But I currently working with the v3 and the trellis stack seems to be a big problem to handle.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'crb_load');
function crb_load()
{
    \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();
}

add_action('carbon_fields_register_fields', 'crb_attach_theme_options');
function crb_attach_theme_options()
{
    Container::make('theme_options', __('Theme Options', 'crb'))->add_fields(
        array(Field::make('rich_text', 'crb_footer_copyright', 'Copyright'))
    );

    Container::make('post_meta', 'Homepage slider')
        ->show_on_template('templates/custom-template.php')
        ->add_fields(array(
            Field::make('map', 'crb_location')->set_position(
                37.423156,
                -122.084917,
                14
            ),
            Field::make('sidebar', 'crb_custom_sidebar'),
            Field::make('image', 'crb_photo')
        ));

    Block::make(__('My Shiny Gutenberg Block'))
        ->add_fields(array(
            Field::make('text', 'heading', __('Block Heading')),
            Field::make('image', 'image', __('Block Image')),
            Field::make('rich_text', 'content', __('Block Content'))
        ))
        ->set_render_callback(function ($block) {
            ?>

        <div class="block">
            <div class="block__heading">
                <h1><?php echo esc_html($block['heading']); ?></h1>
            </div><!– /.block__heading –>
            <div class="block__image">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($block['image'], 'full'); ?>
            </div><!– /.block__image –>

            <div class="block__content">
                <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $block['content']); ?>
            </div><!– /.block__content –>
        </div><!– /.block –>

        <?php
        });
}
```

```
GET http://localhost:3000/wp/core/Libraries/Sidebar_Manager/assets/js/app.js?ver=3.1.3 404 (Not Found)
admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1879 GET http://localhost:3000/wp/build/classic/vendor.js?ver=3.1.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1880 GET http://localhost:3000/wp/build/classic/core.js?ver=3.1.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1881 GET http://localhost:3000/wp/build/classic/metaboxes.js?ver=3.1.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1879 GET http://localhost:3000/wp/build/classic/vendor.js?ver=3.1.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1880 GET http://localhost:3000/wp/build/classic/core.js?ver=3.1.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1881 GET http://localhost:3000/wp/build/classic/metaboxes.js?ver=3.1.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1994 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
    at admin.php?page=crb_carbon_fields_container_theme_options.php:1994
```

There are the errors, I don't know how and to clear the path of all of this calls.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Same problem as https://community.carbonfields.net/t/carbon-fields-admin-plugin-attempts-to-load-javascript-from-wrong-url/104/2

Comment: Tried with `require_once ABSPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';` too